# Image Binding in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have the following piece of code

```
ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageUrl") %>'
```

I've got a `GridView` I want to show images on a `ItemTemplate`
I have a `Database` where I'm saving on the name of the images e.g --> *img1.jpg*

I want to append the full path of the image at before its name so It can be viewed on the `ItemTemplate` on the `GridView`.

I tried to use concat, or the `+` operator but it doesn't seem to work
can any1 tell me what 2 do ???

Comment: have you tried to use Eval instead of Bind? Where exactly did you put concatination of strings? <%# Eval("asdf") + "something %> should work. Maybe <%# Eval("asdf").ToString() + "something %> could fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline `Eval` like this `ImageUrl='<%# "path/to/image" + Bind("ImageUrl") %>'`

No need to use `Bind`. Its used for two-way, read/write databinding.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this it ll works

' height="120" width="180" alt="" />
' OnClick="BtnImg_Click" height="120" width="180"/>

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <%-- <img src='/gallery/catalog/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Thumb") %>' height="120" width="180" alt="" />
--%>                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"/gallery/catalog/"+ Eval("Thumb") %>' OnClick="BtnView_Click" height="120" width="180"/>
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: update your answer please and post the code from you comment in your answer